# Converting a 4 to 20 mA signal to 0 to 5V

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am trying to convert a 4 to 20 mA signal to 0 to 5V.

Till now I just used a 250 Ohm resistor to convert my signal to 1V to 5V.
Now I am trying to increase the resolution by adding a OpAmp.

When applying a constant voltage it will function but adding my sensor fails.

The first picture fails, whereas the last picture works. Is someone able to tell what I am doing wrong?
[image]

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: Final Circuit**
[image]

Comment: "Fails" - what does that mean? Doctor doctor I'm ill but you have to guess my symptoms.

Comment: with 4 mA i would 0V at the red arrow, when I run the simulation it will produce -200V (at the bottom picture with 1 V it is 0V). 20mA gives 100V where it should deliver 5V (5V at the bottom picutre delivers 5V)

Comment: Your feedback resistors should be two orders of magnitude larger, and you need to lose C2 to avoid instability.

Comment: In addition to other comments, in general you should *measure* signals from about 3.6mA to maybe 22 or 24mA and operation should not be affected by 25-30mA (to account for sensor fault and overrange).

Comment: THanks for the input, the sensor I am using does not have any fault or overrange (because it is a linear sensor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R4 and R5 are another load in parallel with your R6 in the top diagram, reducing the total load on the 4-20 signal to 118 ohms.  That is a problem.
Before you play with subtracting 1V from the overall output, buffer your 4-20mA signal through an op-amp to get the 1-5V signal, then you can perform additional operations on that.

One thing, be aware that the floor value (whatever voltage you get at 4mA) is often used to determine if the loop is broken or the transmitter has failed.  By normalizing things, your floor value will go negative in that case, which could be a problem downstream.

Comment: Thanks this did the trick, edited my post to the final circuit